# Excel Formula or VBA coding

Tags: excel

I want to add two value:

> 19:20:30 and 02:00:00

Result should be:

> 21:20:30

How i do that in excel?

Comment: What have you tried doing? What results did you get? This also needs the formatting corrected.

Comment: Its in General Format

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's website says it's as easy as summing the fields.

[Add or subtract time](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-subtract-time-HA102809662.aspx)

Did you try that?